# Slow boot after installing separate distro

Tags: boot, partitioning, boot-time

So I have been searching for a solution for my problem for weeks now but was not able to find anything. Although topics that I found were sometimes similar/related they did not solve my specific problem in the end.

I started out with a notebook that had Windows preinstalled and I installed Ubuntu 15.10 on a separate partition additionally. After that, Ubuntu started up within 20 - 30 seconds... or at least quick enough for me to assume it's a boot at suitable pace.

Then I made another partition and installed a Debian distro. After that, the Ubuntu boot became painfully slow, like 5 minutes or so. I managed to enable verbose boot, so I could see what the system is taking so long with.

There appears to be two times when the system hangs during the boot. Once is when the verbose output reaches something that has to do with Bluetooth,  but the second and more significant hang apparently happens during the time something is done to the swap.

The attached image shows where the system hangs during boot. The code is the output from `systemd-analyze critical-chain` .

[image]

```
graphical.target @1min 34.575s
└─multi-user.target @1min 34.575s
  └─getty.target @1min 34.575s
    └─getty@tty1.service @1min 34.575s
      └─rc-local.service @1min 31.748s +199ms
        └─network-online.target @1min 31.746s
          └─network.target @1min 31.745s
            └─wpa_supplicant.service @1min 31.954s +62ms
              └─basic.target @1min 31.545s
                └─sockets.target @1min 31.545s
                  └─uuidd.socket @1min 31.544s
                    └─sysinit.target @1min 31.532s
                      └─systemd-rfkill@rfkill0.service @22.681s +3ms
                        └─system-systemd\x2drfkill.slice @3.393s
                          └─system.slice @1.295s
                            └─-.slice @1.294s
```

My system:

- Intel Core i5
- 12GB RAM
- 1TB HDD
- NVIDIA GeForce 840M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the additional partition with the Debian installation is not related to the slowdown. The most likely causes are: corruption of your Ubuntu installation, or bad system updates. The easiest solution is to avoid debugging things at this point. As you haven't invested many hours in configuring your Ubuntu install, I recommend just formatting over and then reinstalling Ubuntu. Also, just to rule out Windows interference, it's currently best to change partitions from within Windows.